# Phonegap + jQuery Ajax Post not working

Tags: jquery, ajax, cordova

I am trying to send data to a local page as POST data, from a phonegap app that I am working on using jQuery:

```
 $.ajax({
          method: "POST",
          url: "http://.../api_return.php",
          data: { name: "John", location: "Boston" }
        })
          .done(function( msg ) {
            alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
          });
```

on my `api_return.php` page I have the following code:

```
<?php
print_r($_REQUEST);
?>
```

The strange thing is that if I make the `url: "http://.../api_return.php?test=true",` then my php returns the `test=true`, I cannot get it to return `POST` data.

I have tried:
`<access origin="*" />` in `config.xml`
`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />` in AndroidManifest.xml

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I managed to get it to work, but unfortunately I do not know which change ended up making this work. Here is a list of the changes I made:

1) add `<access origin="*" />` in config.xml

2) add `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />` in AndroidManifest.xml

3) add `connect-src *;` inside of `content=""` for the meta tag: `<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="" />`

4) Wrapped data in JSON.stringify. Ending ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://www.example.com/apicallback.php", // Example 
    data: JSON.stringify({ "name": "John", "location": "Boston" }),
    success: function(response) {
        console.log(response);
        alert(JSON.stringify(response));
    },
    error: function(e) {
        alert('Error: ' + e.message);
    }
});
```

5) Redirected to a second URL (one that was not using `RewriteCond` in the .htaccess folder)

Comment: Could you please give some more information? Maybe show the .htaccess file and the html changes you've made. I've been struggling to get this right.

Answer (score 2):

You may also check on `"Content-type":"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"` in your request header.

It may happen that you can find your post input in raw `php://input` but couldn't find in `$_POST` if you send without `"Content-type":"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"`.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem might be with your PHP:

```
 <?php
   echo json_encode($_POST);
 ?>
```

Comment: Nope, tested that as well, it returns `Data Saved: []` = blank :/

Answer (score 0):

For your $.ajax some versions of JQuery have known issues for setting the method. Use "type" instead.

```
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://.../api_return.php",
        data: { name: "John", location: "Boston" },
        cache: false,
        type: 'POST',
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data);
            console.log(data)
        }
    });
```

Comment: Just tried this as well and still nothing, I am thinking it is related to cordova / phonegap because I know the code works normally, I've tried type: / method: and success: / .done

Comment: Yes `receivedEvent: function(id) {` like I said above, it works fine if I am using GET the problem is that the receiving end requires POST data.

Comment: Don't see why there should be a problem, i'd suggest using a tool like Fiddler, to see what's happening on a network level. http://www.telerik.com/fiddler

Answer (score 0):

Using your options I was stuck at this for a while. I figured that option 3 is the important one!

1. Add  in config.xml
2. Add  in AndroidManifest.xml
3. **Assign `connect-src *;` to `content=""` for the meta tag: `<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="" />`**

The error that I saw was something like:

> *failed to execute 'open' on 'xmlhttprequest' refused to connect*

So, this is what I used for the **Content Security Policy**:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" 
    content="default-src * 'self' 'unsafe-inline' data: gap: 'unsafe-eval';
    style-src * 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; 
    connect-src * ; 
    script-src * 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; 
    media-src *">
```

And it worked!