# cannot post /file.php with ajax request

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, phonegap

My request returns a **404 Not Found** when I send an `AJAX POST request`. I cannot `POST /accountf.php`. This is my code:

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'accountf.php',
  data: {
    "getclient": true
  },
  type: 'post',
  success: function(output) {
    alert(output);
  },
  error: function(xhr) {
    alert("An error occured: " + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText);
  }
});
```

However when I use `get` it returns the whole PHP file in response.

[image]

Comment: Well, maybe because `accountf.php` is not existing at this path?!

Comment: `However when I use get it returns the whole PHP file in response.` If you mean that it returns your actual PHP code instead of the HTML it generates, then it sounds like either your server does not support PHP, or it's not configured correctly.

Comment: @CagatayUlubay if it works for GET but not for POST that would not seem to be the case

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Ah, yea that part was easily to miss(understand).

Comment: can you include the code of your php file?

Comment: Maybe the `phonegap` Tag is part of the solution. Can you try something out of this thread? [Phonegap + jQuery AJAX Post not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32618363/phonegap-jquery-ajax-post-not-working)

Comment: accountf exist 
get method work fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i just change the request path to my xammp htdocs folder 
and paste my php files there now its working
as

```
$.post('http://localhost/bizmanager/backend/accountf.php',
        { "getclient": true },
        function(data,status){
            alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
        });
```

thank you guys

Answer (score -1):

Are you trying to post from an angular javascript to PHP, Make sure your apache/iis is running, and i think the address needs to be handled with :80  or similar it cannot be the angular/Node.js port

Comment: That I would assume is a typo introduced when the OP created the questions and not what is actully in the code

Comment: It might be a good idea to delete this before someone downvotes it